# completely self-contained virtual environment

Tags: python, virtualenv, python-venv

I create a `python3` virtual environment (explicitly avoiding symlinks, with `--copies`):

```
» python3 -m venv --without-pip --copies venv
```

This is my complete virtual environment now:

```
» tree venv/
venv/
├── bin
│   ├── activate
│   ├── activate.csh
│   ├── activate.fish
│   ├── python
│   └── python3
├── include
├── lib
│   └── python3.4
│       └── site-packages
├── lib64 -> lib
└── pyvenv.cfg
```

I disable the `PYTHONPATH`, to make sure nothing is leaking from outside:

```
» PYTHONPATH=""
```

Activate the venv:

```
» source venv/bin/activate
```

Verify that `activate` has not polluted my `PYTHONPATH`:

```
» echo $PYTHONPATH
```

(blank, as expected)

I am using the right python:

```
» which python
/foo/bar/venv/bin/python
```

But the system modules are still being accessed:

```
» python 
Python 3.4.3 (default, Oct 14 2015, 20:28:29) 
[GCC 4.8.4] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import unittest
>>> print(unittest)
<module 'unittest' from '/usr/lib/python3.4/unittest/__init__.py'>
>>>
```

I would expect the `import unittest` statement to fail, since the virtual environment has no such module.

I would like to know:

- Why are system packages accessed when in a virtualenv?
- How can I create a completely self-contained virtual environment?

Comment: Since python 3.11 the [venv docs](https://docs.python.org/3.11/library/venv.html) explicitly say: *"Not considered as movable or copyable – you just recreate the same environment in the target location."*

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If I recall correctly the core system packages are symlinked, so they are the same files (partly to keep the size of the virtualenv down).

The default is not to include the `site-packages` directory, so it won't access 3rd party libraries that have been installed.

If you want to truly isolated and self-contained virtual environment, you might be better off looking at [docker](https://www.docker.com/).

Virtualenv is really more of a lightweight way of managing different 3rd party installed packages for different apps.

EDIT:

It looks like `--always-copy` doesn't actually always copy all files:

[virtualenv doesn't copy all .py files from the lib/python directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23258029/virtualenv-doesnt-copy-all-py-files-from-the-lib-python-directory)

Digging into the source and it looks like there's a smallish set of modules that are deemed to be "required" and these are the ones that are copied:

https://github.com/pypa/virtualenv/blob/ac4ea65b14270caeac56b1e1e64c56928037ebe2/virtualenv.py#L116

Edit 2:

You can see that the old python directories still appear in the `sys.path`, but after the directories for the virtualenv itself:

```
>>> import sys
>>> sys.path
['', '/home/john/venv/lib/python2.7', 
'/home/john/venv/lib/python2.7/plat-linux2', 
'/home/john/venv/lib/python2.7/lib-tk',
'/home/john/venv/lib/python2.7/lib-old', 
'/home/john/venv/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload', '/usr/lib/python2.7',
'/usr/lib/python2.7/plat-linux2',
'/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-tk',
'/home/john/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages',
'/home/john/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages']
```

Comment: Please note that I am using `--copies`: no symlinks are used (as seen in the directory tree). Docker is overkill for my needs: I can *live* with this situation, but I want to understand the background issues. Maybe a built-in PYTHONPATH in the system's python binary (which gets copied to the virtualenv)? How is this done? The system `python` binary is installed (in this case) with `apt get`, so how would the python binary know where it is installed (specially after being copied around!)?

Comment: Hadn't spotted the `--copies` there.  I tested out using `--always-copy` locally (is `--copies` the older name?) and that does copy the files, but strangely *not* for unittest.  If you try the same test for the `os` module, you should see that gives you the right path.

Comment: I do not have the `--always-copy` option, but `--copies`. I do not know which one is older. I am using python 3.4.3, and you?

Comment: And thanks for your explanation. It clarifies *why* are certain packages not copied with virtualenv (for me nothing is copied, actually, who knows why), but I still would like to know how can the python in the virtualenv use system packages (like unittest)

Comment: I was actually trying this with virtualenv 13.1.2 (on linux), but the docs only seem to refer to `--always-copy`. Odd.

Comment: The old python is still referenced on the PYTHONPATH - possible hardcoded in a binary.

Comment: Ok, got it. As you say, probably embedded in the python binary during compilation. As mentioned, my python is installed with apt, so using pre-compiled packages. It seems odd that such "installation-phase" info is hardcoded in a binary, though: it makes the installation directory for the binary not really relocatable (so basically, it can only be correctly installed in the path hardcoded during compilation time)

Comment: You can use `--relocatable` to make the virtualenv movable.  It's quite common for binaries to have a hardcoded library path though, as it means you can multiple versions installed with different paths encoded in them.  Everything then just works as expected.

Comment: Thanks, I know about `--relocatable`, but that is another matter altogether. What annoys me is that the python binary itself (not the virtualenv), has a hardcoded dependency to an installation path which is **none of its business**. I am the one to install it wherever I see fit (or `apt` in case of system python, or `virtualenv` in case of the virtualenv's python).

Comment: I would be less annoyed with python having a hardcoded *relative* reference to a `lib` path, but not with an absolute path. I assume these are linux/unix conventions, and there is surely a rationale of why this is the case (my last *linux from scratch* installation was done some time ago), but it is still surprising.

Comment: This is almost ten years old, but still, some disambiguation would be useful: it appears OP is asking about `venv` from the Python *standard library*, whereas this answer refers to `pypa/virtualenv`. Is that correct? I think this would also explain the `--copies` vs `--always-copy` confusion above.

Answer (score 0):

you can build python from source on an old Linux; then the python will be complete self-contained and able to run on many Linux.

in the reference link, it is the step detail to build python 3.6 on centos 5 in container env. the output can be used in many Linux like debian 10, centos 6, 7, 8, photon 3, alpine, ...

- `readline-devel`: enable python command line history
- `sqlite-devel`: enable sqlite support
- `expat-devel`: enable xmltree support
- `bzip2-devel`: enable bzip2 support
- compile SSL from source to avoid dynamic lib link
- if higher version of python, maybe you also need to compile higher version of gcc to get sth like full C++11 and higher support
- after compiling, you need to download setuptools and pip from pypi.python.org and do `python setup.py install` to get pip ready for this standalone python.

ref: https://github.com/stallpool/track-network-traffic#mitmproxy-for-manylinux