# How to make venv completely portable?

Tags: linux, centos, virtualenv, python-venv

I want to create a [`venv`](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/venv.html) environment (not [`virtualenv`](https://virtualenv.pypa.io/en/latest/)) using the following commands:

```
sudo apt-get install python3.8-venv
python3.8 -m venv venv_name
source venv_name/bin/activate
```

But it seems to be that it contains dependency on the system where it is created and it creates problems whenever I want to make it portable. That means, I want when I copy this folder along with my project and run it in another machine, it will work without making any changes.

But I am unable to activate the environment (it gets activated but the interpreter still uses system's `python` and `pip`.

Therefore, I tried making another `venv` in the second computer and copied the `lib` and `lib64` folders from the older `venv` to this newer `venv` (without replacing existing files) but getting the following error this time:

```
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/ctypes/__init__.py" line 7, in <module>
    from _ctypes import Union, Structure, Array
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named '_ctypes'
```

But interesting thing is, if you notice, the newly created `venv` in the new machine also searching the missing package in its local directory and not in the `venv`.

How do I make the `venv` portable along with all its dependencies and  reliably deploy in another device just by activating it?

Comment: similar: https://stackoverflow.com/q/35035274

Comment: From the [venv docs](https://docs.python.org/3.11/library/venv.html): *"A virtual environment is (amongst other things): ... Not considered as movable or copyable – you just recreate the same environment in the target location."*

Answer (score 4):

**Disclaimer**: None of this is my work, I just found this blog-post and will briefly summarize: https://aarongorka.com/blog/portable-virtualenv/ [archived](https://web.archive.org/web/20201130233251/https://aarongorka.com/blog/portable-virtualenv/)

Caveat: This only works (semi-reliably) among *Linux* machines. **Don't use in production!**

The first step is to get copies of your python-executables in the `venv/bin` folder, so be sure to specify [`--copies`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/venv.html#creating-virtual-environments) when creating the virtual environment:

> python3 -m venv --copies venv

All that's left seems to be changing the hardcoded absolute paths into relative paths, using your tool of choice. In the blogpost, they use `pwd` after changing to the venv-parent-directory whenever `venv/bin/activate` is run.

> sed -i '43s/.*/VIRTUAL_ENV="$(cd "$(dirname "$(dirname "${BASH_SOURCE[0]}" )")" && pwd)"/' venv/bin/activate

Then, similarly all pip-scripts need to be adapted to run execution with the local python

> sed -i '1s/.*/#!/usr/bin/env python/' venv/bin/pip*

BUT, the real problem starts when installing new modules. I would expect most modules to behave nicely, but there will be those that hardcode expected path-structures or similarly thwart any work towards replacing path dependencies.

However: I find this trick is very useful to share a single folder among developers for finding elusive bugs.

Answer (score 2):

You can use python embedded https://www.python.org/ftp/python/3.12.0/python-3.12.0-embed-amd64.zip.

Once you download it, download pip from google by writing 'get pip' as search query

[get-pip.py](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=2ahUKEwjA7JOUkOyBAxVNTGwGHUsjDzQQFnoECA0QAQ&url=https%3A%2F%2Fbootstrap.pypa.io%2Fget-pip.py&usg=AOvVaw0zKVO_zW0nkF7s0zdjWFNj&opi=89978449)

Copy `get_pip.py` to that folder. Run the file with the `python.exe` of that directory. E.g., `./python.exe ./get-pip.py`

Open `python312._pth` and uncomment the `import` statement.

Copy the path to the python.exe inside the folder and use something like

```
./python-3.12.0-embed-amd64/python.exe pip install -r ./requirements.txt
./python-3.12.0-embed-amd64/python.exe ./main.py
```

to install the packages and run your py file. I used a powershell script to run those commands.

Comment: In my project, I needed to allow `pip install` after distribution, so this method was really helpful. Thank you.