# virtual environment with self contained python executables

Tags: python, virtualenv, python-venv

I am trying to create a virtual environment that uses its own python interpreter and pip rather than relying on system python, so that venv will work even though system python uninstalled.

I have used virtualenv as my system runs windows , I think by default it uses symbolic links rather copying binary executables. I headed to virtualenv docs and found --copies argument for creating env specific python executable.
I used "virtualenv --copies myenv" command and it is still creating symbolic links. How can I get copy of the python executables rather than symbolic links.

Comment: A virtualenv is not designed or intended to create a portable Python installation. As documented in [How to make venv completely portable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68392703/how-to-make-venv-completely-portable) it can _sorta_ be done, but not reliably, or with support for operating systems other than Linux.

Comment: I am quite sure it is not possible as stated already. As far as I know, not only the virtual environments are not portable, but the CPython interpreters are not portable either (where by "portable" I mean "can be copied and pasted somewhere else". -- For sure there are ways, but it will not be without pain. -- Without knowing why really you want to do that beyond "_so that venv will work even though system python uninstalled_" it is difficult to direct you towards alternative solutions (which there are plenty of) that would be meaningful to your use case.

Answer (score 0):

You can force copying the executables by using the `--always-copy` option, for more info you can check: https://virtualenv.pypa.io/en/latest/cli_interface.html#always-copy

EDIT: for Windows you can use Python 3.11.2 or later, `--copies` just copies the executables (I tested it with scoop installed Python 3.11.2 : `scoop install python`)

Comment: I used that too, but still it creating symlinks and not copying python interpreter. To check this I deleted system python and run python in created virtual env, it has given following error "No Python at 'c:\users\mahesh\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\python.exe' " which means that symlinks created. what should I do???

Comment: Did you tried copying it manually ?

Comment: I test it with python 3.11.2 and it works with `--copies`, no symlinks, also --always-copy was removed

Comment: I dont know how to do it manually, as there is cfg file that points to the system python , and i am using 3.7.6 version for creating virtual env.

Comment: I also tested using 3.11.2 but still creating symlinks and given the following error. "(env_3) D:\_Mahesh\project>python
No Python at '"C:\Users\mahesh\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\python.exe'" . I dont know whats going wrong