# Managing inhouse python versions

Tags: python, package, repository, bitbucket, version

I'm setting up a python server(Windows)/repository(bitbucket) and it seems like it'd be a headache to have everyone go out on their own and install/manage a specified version of python/packages. Ideally I'd like to be able to point at a version on X machine or X repository and have it easily replace system variables and the old version on Y machine. Does anyone have any advice?

I've tried google but I mostly get results about managing multiple python versions on one machine.

Comment: I would build a docker container that defined your standard. After that, I think there are strategies to make an environment semi-portable https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68392703/how-to-make-venv-completely-portable

Answer (score 0):

Generally if you use conda in general, you can manage different version of python and packages on a per-project level. Normally, on a per-project basis:

```
# this will save an env
conda list --explicit > spec-file.txt
# this will recreate the environment in a new conda environment on the target machine
conda install --name myenv --file spec-file.txt
```

The spec file is something htat would get checked into source control